# dynamic image name in CloudBuilder

Tags: bash, docker, google-cloud-build

I am building docker images with dynamic tags in CloudBuilder. I would like to be able to then run that same image, but I'm having trouble getting it to work.

Here's what I've got:

```yaml
steps:
- id: "Store value for docker image tag"
  name: ubuntu
  entrypoint: bash
  args:
   - -c
   - date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S > /workspace/image_tag.txt
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  entrypoint: bash
  args: [ '-c', 'docker build -t gcr.io/blah/my_image:$(cat /workspace/image_tag.txt) -f src/Dockerfile ./src' ]
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  entrypoint: bash
  args: [ '-c', 'docker push gcr.io/blah/my_image:$(cat /workspace/image_tag.txt)' ]
...

- name: 'gcr.io/blah/my_image:$(cat /workspace/image_tag.txt)'
  entrypoint: /bin/sh
  args:
  - -c
#  - execute some commands and script within the image...
```

(`gcr.io/blah/my_image` *is* a custom builder)

Obviously, the name 'gcr.io/blah/my_image:$(cat /workspace/image_tag.txt)' does not work, I get an error:

> Your build failed to run: generic::invalid_argument: invalid build: invalid build step name "gcr.io/blah/my_image:$(cat /workspace/image_tag.txt)": could not parse reference: gcr.io/blah/my_image:$(cat /workspace/image_tag.txt)

The image gets pushed fine, but I want the a step that runs the image that got pushed earlier. Did I just mess up the syntax? If I can't do it as easily as I want, is there some other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to interpret the content, use " instead of ', like that

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  entrypoint: bash
  args: [ '-c', "docker build -t gcr.io/blah/my_image:$(cat /workspace/image_tag.txt) -f src/Dockerfile ./src" ]
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  entrypoint: bash
  args: [ '-c', "docker push gcr.io/blah/my_image:$(cat /workspace/image_tag.txt)" ]
```

Comment: Actually, it works fine for me as it is with single quotes in the args list, but I guess I could try double quotes in the `name` field... I'll update after I test it.